# Two capacitors in parallel vs series - electric field?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, capacitance

If we have two parallel plate capacitors in parallel, do the electric fields between their plates have to be the same? What happens if we have a coaxial cable of length $L$, which looks like this:

[image]

One part of it (length $X$) is filled with a dielectric of relative permittivity $\epsilon_r$. Are the two electric fields $E_1$ and $E_2$ between the inner and outer electrodes the same? If we look at the cable as two separate cylindrical capacitors of lengths $X$ and $L-X$, are those capacitors then connected in series or parallel in this case?

Edit: Electric field using Gauss's law (in case $X=\frac{L}{2}$).

Since the two cylindrical capacitors are in parallel, $E_1$ and $E_2$ are the same, so we know, by Gauss's law, that:
$$\oint_S{DdS=Q}$$
$$\epsilon_0E2{\pi}r\frac{l}{2}+\epsilon_0\epsilon_rE2{\pi}r\frac{l}{2}=Q$$
$$\epsilon_0E(1+\epsilon_r){\pi}rl=Q$$
$$E=\frac{Q}{{\pi}rl\epsilon_0(1+\epsilon_r)}$$
I'm not entirely sure if I correctly solved the integral.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it may be considered as connected in parallel
and electric field is same.
since energy stored = 1/2 e°E^2 in upper part
and 1/2 eE^2 in lower
charge stored by 2 are different
lower stores more charge 
so stores more energy

both have same potential difference
Q= CV
Q' = C' V
capacity of both are different.
using gauss law
electric field in both is
E.S=Q/e°.
in second case
E'.S= Q'/e°er
where extra charge is cancelled by extra 'epsilon r'.
so E is same in both cases.

Comment: Then the total charge Q stored in those capacitors is not equally distributed between them. Does that result in different electric fields? If the fields are different, how can the voltage be the same?

Comment: One more thing bothers me, if electric fields are the same, how do we find the electric field? I posted how I did it using Gauss's law, but I'm not entirely sure what Gaussian surface I should take, because the charge is not distributed equally across the whole cable.